# .NET Core Application CPU Hang

Tags: debugging, .net-core, .net-5, coreclr

I'm trying to debug a sporadically/randomly occurring application hang. It seems to happen at random times (especially when debugging the application). This seems to have started around our upgrade to .NET 5.0, but I can't be positive that it's related. We are running on 5.0.302.

When it occurs, the Pause/Break button in Visual Studio does not cause a break in application execution (even with Just My Code disabled). It just times out and eventually prompts me to terminate the application).

I've tried to use dotnet trace to collect CPU telemetry, but it also hangs up.

Taking and exploring a process dump hasn't shown me anything useful yet. I just core CLR code in stack traces.

In Process Explorer, I can see a single core of the CPU pegged indefinitely

I also used WinDbg on a dump file from a hung process and see tons of threads like this:
[image]

The stack trace for such threads doesn't seem to indicate much useful information

This sounds somewhat like this issue... https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42375

but adding TieredCompilation to my build csproj does not seem to fix the issue for me

UPDATE :
These are the top CPU culprits in wpr.exe

[image]

Comment: Does the same hang / CPU thrash happen when you build in release mode?

Comment: I've only seen it happen once in Release mode....it seems to happen much more frequently in Debug mode, but again it seems random

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your app using any libraries / packages that are targeted for lower versions of .NET Core? I highly doubt that this would be the issue though... but I'm curious.

Comment: Only packages that target netstandard. All packages are MS authored. DI, configuration, etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace

Comment: What are you referring me to here? @magicandre1981

Comment: As mentioned in my post, dotnet trace hangs as well. @magicandre1981

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin and run **WPR -start CPU && timeout -1 && WPR -stop HighCPUUsage.etl** open the etl in perfview/WPA to look at the cpu sampling stack

Comment: tried that and it didn't seem to succeed

Comment: you need to install a newer Windows 10 SDK to fix the [capture issue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/performance-diagnostics/wpr-start-and-stop-commands/). Get the [Server 2022 SDK (10.0.20348.0)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)

Comment: have you tried the new WPR.exe from latest  Win10/Server2022 SDK? can you now capture the trace?

Comment: It just hangs at "Press any key to continue ..." @magicandre1981

Comment: I installed the Windows Performance Toolkit using 10.0.20348.0 and it said it installed successfully, but I'm guessing the installer is broken and doesn't actually work since the wpr.exe was not modified by the installer

Comment: The version I'm running apparently is Microsoft Windows Performance Recorder Version 10.0.19041 (CoreSystem)

Comment: the inbox wpr.exe is not updated use the new version **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe"**

Comment: I have the etl file now - what am I looking for specifically?

Comment: follow those guides for [CPU usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) and [Hangs/delays](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis)

Comment: I watched the videos @magicandre1981 and see nothing of relevance in the thread stacks. I looks exclusively like the screenshot in my question

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks kind of like thread exhaustion, but I am not sure how to track down what is spawning all of these threads

Comment: I see 1000+ rows named ".NET ThreadPool Worker"

Comment: you need to [load debug symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-hardware/test/wpt/load-symbols-or-configure-symbol-paths) to see function names

Comment: I loaded symbols and can see stacks now, but I still don't know what I'm looking for. There are thousands of rows with CPU usage all .01% to .1% which add up to my single pegged core of 12%. None of the stack traces show any managed code, except one Task.WhenAll. I don't see any stacks that have any of my own code in it at all.

Comment: Added one more screenshot to the question....they're the top CPU culprits

Comment: ok, looks like GC runs and causes the CPU usage.

Comment: So what does that tell me about the fact that it causes the application to hang? I'm only using ~250MB of memory

Comment: WKS in callstack means Workstation GC is used. Try the ServerGC by adding the entry to the [testhost.exe.config](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1350#issuecomment-354560703)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is that the version of Visual Studio should have support for the specific SDK version of the .NET Core framework.

For example, Visual Studio 2019 (v16.10) has support for .NET Core SDK 5.0.303, while v16.11 has support for the 5.0.400 SDK version of .NET Core (released just yesterday - according to [this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)).

My theory is if your current VS version is v16.11, but you have the 5.0.303 SDK installed only, there maybe some issues with integration.

Comment: And I'm running 16.10

Comment: Just updated to 16.11 and 5.0.400 and it still persists (at least in debug mode)...seems to happy 1 out of every 5 times I debug